# Eigenvectors and Eigenvalues of $a^\dagger a$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, eigenvalue

A common question I have seen on problems sets and on exam papers is as follows (own words):

> Show that $a^\dagger$ and $a$ satisfy the canonical commutation relations. Hence show write down the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $a^\dagger a$.

The expected answer is as follows :

> The eigenvalues are $n=0,1,\ldots$ and the eigenvectors are - spare a normalization: $$(a^\dagger)^n \left|0\right>$$
>   where $a \left|0\right>=0$.

It is clear from the commutation relations that if we have an eigenvalue $\lambda$ then we have a string of eigenvalues:
$$\ldots, \lambda -2,\lambda -1, \lambda, \lambda+1,\lambda+2,\ldots$$
if $\lambda$ is a natural number then this string is bounded by below by $0$ and it is always bounded above by $\infty$. The expected answer I have given above has made two (in my opinion, fairly large) assumptions:

1. There is only one string present. I.e. there is no eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ such that $\lambda_2 \ne \lambda+k$ for some $k \in \Bbb{Z}$.
2. The string that is present has $\lambda \in \Bbb{N}$.

These assumptions hold for the case of the Harmonic oscillator - this can be shown by explicitly solving the Hamiltonian. But often there are no harmonic oscillators in sight - for example in the Fock space representation$^\star$.

Thus my question is: under what circumstances do we expect the above assumptions to be valid and why?

<sub><sup>$\star$ Only an example - not the focus of my question.</sup></sub>

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90051/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23028/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks your second link answers the question - I have marked as duplicate.